# ACRA and LeakCanary

Tags: android, memory-leaks, acra, leakcanary

A recent I begin use LeakCanary. And I Here is my stacktrace:

```
com.my.app.ui.menu.MenuActivity has leaked:
D/LeakCanary: * GC ROOT static org.acra.ACRA.errorReporterSingleton
D/LeakCanary: * references org.acra.ErrorReporter.lastActivityCreated
D/LeakCanary: * leaks com.my.app.ui.menu.MenuActivity instance
```

If I correctly understand, MenuActivity contatins static reference on the field errorReporterSingleton, right? How I can resolve this leak?

Comment: WHat version of ACRA?

Comment: Well that report isn't from ACRA-4.8.5. It has to be ACRA-4.7.0 or earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LeakCanary appearas to be telling to that `org.acra.ErrorReporter.lastActivityCreated` is holding a reference to `com.my.app.ui.menu.MenuActivity`.

LeakCanary is mistaken.

`lastActivityCreated` is a *weak* reference to the last Activity. Ie it will released when there are no strong/direct references.